# find first pair element (int) on a vector and get second (struct)

Tags: c++, sockets, vector, struct

**SOLVED**. see below
I'm running a service like this:

```
int pgsService::startService(int sockfd){
    listen(sockfd,5);
    int c = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&cli_addr,&clilen);
    clients.push_back(std::make_pair(sockfd,cli_addr));
    std::cout << "Accepted:" << c << "\tIP:" << inet_ntoa(cli_addr.sin_addr) << std::endl;
    return c;
}
```

Constructor:

```
pgsService::pgsService(int *fd,int port) {
    bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
    *fd = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
    assert(*fd>0);
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    serv_addr.sin_port=htons(port);
    bind(*fd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
    clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);
}
```

private members:

```
private:
        struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;
        int sfd;
        socklen_t clilen;
        std::vector<std::pair<int, struct sockaddr_in> > clients;
};
```

CompareFirst struct:

```
struct CompareFirst
{
  CompareFirst(int val) : val_(val) {}
  bool operator()(const std::pair<int,struct sockaddr_in>& elem) const {
    return val_ == elem.first;
  }
  private:
    int val_;
};
```

Which starts an instance of a service binding a local port.
This port will serve to chat-like service in a .NET client side application but the server side I'm doing all in C++.

So, after I `pgsService server = pgsService(&sockfd,port);` I call `int client = server.startService(sockfd);`
Described above.
The constructor is only binding at setting the structs etc to the socket server.
When there is a connection:
*testing code only*:

```
write(client,hello.c_str(),hello.length());
void *buf = malloc(512);
memset(buf,0,512);
read(client,buf,512);
std::cout << "From:" << inet_ntoa(server.getClientInfo(client).sin_addr) << ":"<< server.getClientInfo(client).sin_port << "\t - " << (char*)buf << std::endl;
free(buf);
shutdown(client,2);
exit(0);
```

It outputs like:

```
$ ./pgs_service
Accepted:4      IP:127.0.0.1
GETING:0.0.0.0
GETING:0.0.0.0
From:0.0.0.0:0   - LOL
```

I'm trying to hold the clients data information in a vector here:

```
clients.push_back(std::make_pair(sockfd,cli_addr));
```

The getClientInfo method is:

```
struct sockaddr_in pgsService:: getClientInfo(int client){
    std::vector< std::pair <int, struct sockaddr_in> >::iterator it = std::find_if(clients.begin(),clients.end(),CompareFirst(client));
    std::cout << "GETING:" << inet_ntoa(it->second.sin_addr) << std::endl;
    return (it->second);
}
```

So I store in the clients vector that accepts another object of type std::pair.
I push into stack and when I need to get the struct I simply call getClientInfo and it finds using find_if.
The problem is that I believe that the return value is not the actual struct because it sometimes returns some integers like: 83.0.0.0 and then 0.0.0.0 and then 30.0.0.0 . Seems I'm accessing regions of memory I shouldn't and Luckily the program isn't crashing.

I'm doing something wrong? Where? I think it is the way I'm push into the vector OR the way I'm getting the data back.

**SOLUTION**: When I push_back I make "make_pair" with sockfd and I shouldn't. I must push 'c'.

Comment: where is cli_addr initialized?

Comment: inside the constructor. going to edit the question.

Comment: Your edited post still  doesn't initialize or declare cli_addr. I am assuming you are doing that elsewhere.

Comment: You mean in the class? editing second time...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming quite a few things here.

1. You have CompareFirst defined somewhere.
2. Between subsequent calls
   to `startService` I am assuming you are mem-setting `cli_addr` to `0`.

I don't see anything fundamentally wrong with your use of the vector and the std::pair construct in terms of populating the vector after making a pair. The trick however maybe ensuring semantic correctness. Can you check whether `cli_addr` is in-fact populated correctly after accept returns?

Also, instead of pushing the server fd, shouldn't you be pushing the fd returned by accept - in your case `c`? IMO, a better way to accomplish what you are doing is using an associative data-structure like a map or an un-ordered map. Also, for better design, you should evaluate mechanisms such as `select` to handle i/o since your `accept` calls are essentially going to block.

Yet another issue is not checking the return value of the find_if. You should always compare the iterator to clients.end() in order to ensure it is a valid iterator.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm hitting the end of vector. it seems I couldn't find the fd... :/ Can you check again if the CompareFirst is ok?

Comment: The CompareFirst is not the problem, the first in the make_pair should be c and not sockfd.